# Haskell guards and Co

Tags: haskell

Sorry my first post

- a. inputs an integer value;
- b. outputs Negative if the input number was less than zero;
- c.outputs Zero if the input  number was exactly zero;
- d. outputs Natural if the input number was greater than zero.

can someone please help me . What am I doing wrong?

```
snum :: Int->String
snum x
 | x > 0   = "Natural"
 | x == 0   = "Zero"
 | otherwise = "Negative"
```

and why do I think, 'cos haskell tells me so ;)

snum 4 or 0 or (-5) gives me

```
Ambiguous occurrence `snum'
It could refer to either `Main.snum', defined at snum.hs:2:1
                      or `Prelude.snum', imported from Prelude
```

Comment: No-one can help you, because there is no way of knowing what you are doing wrong. http://sscce.org/

Comment: @igrec: please explain yourself better. What is exactly the problem with that piece of code? I tried to answer you, but it is just a guess because I really don't know what could you expect from that code if you don't tell us :)

Comment: @igrec Why do you think you are doing something wrong? You do something, you expect something to happen as a consequence, but instead something else happens instead. You need to tell us all three pieces of information.

Answer (score 5):

There's already a predefined value `snum`.

Possible workarounds:

1. Rename your function, e.g.

   ```
   mySnum :: Int->String
   mySnum x
    | x > 0   = "Natural"
    | x == 0   = "Zero"
    | otherwise = "Negative"
   ```
2. Hide the predefined `snum`, by adding this line at the start of your program:

   ```
   import Prelude hiding (snum)
   ```

But I'm curious: I've never heard of a predefined `snum` before. What are you using to run your Haskell program? GHC? Hugs? Something else? Which version?

Comment: Wow!!! I have killed two hours thinking what is wrong?  Thanks gents and ladies!  About the 'snum' I have changed the function name for posting online. It has another name on my script  ;)) Silly me, Thanks one more time

Comment: It was one of my lecturer's tricks. Homework create function :signum; oddeven.Did you noticed , that?  Damn!!!. All I had to do is change the names sigNum; oddEven. Strange way of making students to remember build in functions.  :) Damn! tahnk s one more time

Answer (score 4):

Your code is correct, and works for me.
Maybe your concern could be about negative numbers, e.g. for calls like `snum -1`? Ih this case rembember that you have to wrap them in parenthesis, or haskell will think  that `-` is a binary infix operator for subtraction (and consequently it will try to subtract 1 from `snum`, which is a function and not a number): `snum (-1) == "Negative"` will return `True`.